# NumPy - How to broadcast arrays of different shapes

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray

I have a 200 x 200 array of vectors. Its shape is `(200, 200, 3)`.

I also have an array of 22 vectors. Its shape is `(22,3)`.

I want to subtract all 22 vectors in the second array from each vector in the first array. The output should have shape `(200, 200, 22, 3)`.

I'd like to perform an operation like

```
first - second
```

But I get the error

```
*** ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (200,200,3) (22,3)
```

I think I need to pad the first array somehow in order to allow NumPy to broadcast the arrays together. How do I tell NumPy how to perform the broadcast?

Comment: Doesn't subtracting 3D vectors produce another 3D vector? How is the output shape (200, 200, 22)? Shoudn't it be (200, 200, 22, 3)?

Comment: You're right, fixed.

Comment: `first[:,:,None,:] - second`; or to be a bit more explicit `first[:,:,None,:] - second[None,None,:,:]`.  In other words imagine where the two arrays have to be expanded to fit in the target (200,200,22,3) array.

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1st Array: `200 X 200 X 3`
2nd Array:        `22 X 3`

In this case, any Arithmetic operation you perform on this, will result in `(200, 200, 3)`.

You might have received the error if you tried: `2nd Array - 1st Array`

You can check this out: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a particular axis to broadcast for any operation, it needs to have a size of `1` in that axis. So if `a.shape` is `(200,200,3)`, and `b.shape` is `(22,3)`, and the output shape you want is `(200,200,22,3)`, then you will need to do some reshaping before doing the operation.

```
c = a.reshape(200,200,1,3) - b.reshape(1,1,22,3)
```

Now `c.shape` is `(200,200,22,3)`. The code above will accomplish the task you want on subtracting the 22 3D vectors from the 40000 vectors.

I personally believe it is much easier to think of what each axis represents for your tensors, and just adjust tensor shapes or use `np.transpose` as needed for whatever application you are using tensors for. Working with multi-dimensional tensors takes some getting used to. But once you get the hang of it it's very easy, and I think pretty cool.